# Access NodePort Service Outside Kubeadm K8S Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, service-node-port-range

I have two Ubuntu VMs created using Oracle Virtual Box on my Windows 11 laptop. I setup a k8s cluster using kubeadm with these two Ubuntu VMs, one of them is a master node and an another one is a worker node. Both the nodes are running with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and docker://20.10.7. I deployed my spring boot app into the k8s cluster and exposed a node port service for my spring boot app with port 30000, but I am not really sure on how to access my node port service on the internet outside my cluster. Could you please help me with this issue?

[image: kubectl get nodes -o wide]
[image: kubectl get svc -o wide]

Following are the IP address of my nodes in k8s cluster - master [192.168.254.94] and worker [192.168.254.95]. I tried with the following urls but none of them worked

http://192.168.254.94:30000/swagger-ui.html
http://192.168.254.95:30000/swagger-ui.html

These above urls throwing message which says refused to connect

http://192.168.9.13:30000/swagger-ui.html
http://192.168.9.14:30000/swagger-ui.html

These above urls says that the site cannot be reached

Below is the content of my application.yaml which I used for deploying the spring boot app and its corresponding service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   name: dealer-engine
spec:
   replicas: 1
   selector:
      matchLabels:
         app: dealer-engine
   template:
      metadata:
        labels:
           app: dealer-engine
      spec:
         containers:
            - name: dealer-engine
              image: moviepopcorn/dealer_engine:0.0.1
              ports:
                 - containerPort: 9090
              env:
                 - name: MONGO_URL
                   value: mongodb://mongo-service:27017/mazda
              imagePullPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: dealer-engine
spec:
   type: NodePort
   selector:
      app: dealer-engine
   ports:
      - port: 9091
        targetPort: 9090
        nodePort: 30000
   externalIPs:
    - 10.0.0.12
```

I am a beginner in k8s so please help me on how I can access my node port service outside my k8s cluster.

Comment: Can you ping your VMs from Windows?

Comment: @loki Yes. I can ping them using the following IPS 192.168.254.94 and 192.168.254.95

Comment: change `service.spec .externalIPs` to 192.168.254.94, OR just delete it.

Comment: It’s not working even if I delete the external IP.

Comment: Try to CURL from a POD to the clusterIP.

Comment: As suggested above try to create another pod within the cluster and run `curl` from it. I'm not sure if url `swagger-ui.html` is valid for this application. What happens if you curl/open `http://192.168.9.13:30000`? Also check networking in VirtualBox, it shouldn't be set to NAT.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new simple Springboot application which returns "Hello world!!!" back to the user when the following endpoint "/helloWorld" is invoked. I deployed this spring boot app into my k8s cluster using the below yaml configuration

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   name: hello-world
spec:
   replicas: 1
   selector:
      matchLabels:
         app: hello-world
   template:
      metadata:
        labels:
           app: hello-world
      spec:
         containers:
            - name: hello-world
              image: moviepopcorn/hello_world:0.0.1
              ports:
                 - containerPort: 9091
              imagePullPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: hello-world
spec:
   type: NodePort
   selector:
      app: hello-world
   ports:
      - port: 9091
        targetPort: 9091
        nodePort: 30001
```

After successful deployment, I am able to access the helloWorld endpoint using the following url <K8S_MASTER_NODE_IP>:<NODE_PORT (30001)>.

Thank you all for your answers and inputs. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you install any CNI plugin like flannel?

If yes, Check your CIDR setting here

```sh
kubectl get node k8s-master -o yaml | grep podCIDR:
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system kube-flannel-cfg -o yaml | grep '"Network":'
```

Basically yes, CNI is must. flannel is the most simple one.

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network

> You must deploy a Container Network Interface (CNI) based Pod network add-on so that your Pods can communicate with each other. Cluster DNS (CoreDNS) will not start up before a network is installed.

1. Download cni pulgin on every server.

```sh
# download cni plugin
wget https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/releases/download/v0.9.1/cni-plugins-linux-amd64-v0.9.1.tgz
sudo mkdir -p /opt/cni/bin
sudo tar -xzvf cni-plugins-linux-amd64-v0.9.1.tgz -C /opt/cni/bin
```

2. Reset you cluster

```sh
kubeadm reset
```

3. Init your cluster with cidr setting must same as flannel config, default `10.244.0.0`

```sh
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

4. Apply cni plugin.

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Comment: I do not have flannel installed. Do I have to install it?

Comment: @SrinivasanRamu I think you already have one plugin. Your node should not show ready otherwise.

Comment: @loki Yes. You are correct. I did a new spring boot app with one get controller which returns a simple message. Deployed this application and its corresponding service as NodePort, I am able to access my springboot app on my localhost browser using master node ip address:nodeport. Now I need to find out on how I can access the swagger ui of my spring boot. Thank you for your inputs.